# Dual Boot Windows-Android on PC: How to switch OS programmatically?

Tags: android, windows, boot, bcdedit

**In Windows, are there some command lines that would make the machine understand that Android should be the next boot (for one boot only -so once I reboot from Android I fall back into Windows)?**

I am working on a notebook ASUS X200CA, UEFI-based machine, dualboot: Windows 8.1 and Android 7.1 (two different partitions).
When Android is installed, I get Grub2, so at reboot I can manually choose between Windows or Android. However, I want to be able to switch OS programmatically.

Basically, I am looking for the equivalent of Linux - `efibootmgr -n xxxx` or `grub-reboot x` before using `reboot` - that I could implement on Windows.

I tried to use `bcdedit /enum firmware` to check the ID associated to Android then ran `bcdedit /bootsequence {ID}`. At reboot, this led to an error like:

> File: \efi\Android\BOOTx64.EFI Status:0xc000000d Info: The application
>   or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is
>   missing or contains error

(NB: secure boot disabled, fastboot disabled)

- I tried to use *EasyBCD*, but since this is an UEFI-based machine I
  didn't get very far.
- I added Android to Windows Boot Loader using *BOOTMGR*, restarted, got
  to Windows Boot Loader, found the Android option, manually picked it
  and got the same error message (see above).
- I tried *Grub2win*, you can modify the EFI boot order with it, but it
  seems that it's not for one boot only.
- I know that some tablets dual boot Windows-Android have *wintoand.exe* that allows to switch but I am not sure what's behind. Moreover, I would prefer to not have to use any software: I want to know what command lines can achieve what I need.

If you have some ideas of how to solve this or anything to read that could guide me, Thanks for sharing in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Grub2Win has the function you are looking for. Documentation will be found in the Grub2Win help under keyword **Reboot**.

The command format is:

**C:\grub2\grub2win    reboot    x**

where x is the menu selection number. This can be run from the Windows command line or a .bat file.

You will receive a message that the reboot has been scheduled.

If you wish to cancel a previously scheduled reboot, use this command:

**C:\grub2\grub2win    reboot    none**

Hope this helps.

Dave